# Connecting to existing Jupyter server (kernel) on remote machine

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I saw similar questions, but they refered to older versions of jupyter..

I had a (very) long process running on jupyter notebook on AWS remote machine, and I forgot to write the resulting dataframe after the computation was complete. At some point, the ssh connection was terminated (Broken pipe), and the notebook on the browser lost connection to the kernel.

[image]

I ran `ps -aux | grep jupyter`, `ps -aux | grep ipykernel` , and saw that the process is still out there.

What are the steps that I should take in order to reconnect to the (existing) jupyter kernel and save the data? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try issuing command `jupyter notebook list`

Here is the output for my PC

```
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/?token=caxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2e38 :: F:\user\project1
http://localhost:8888/?token=5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc7f :: F:\user\project2
```

Although, the first server is invalid (but it was valid some time ago), the second one is OK, I can open displayed link.